# I want to increase the size of an image without increasing navigation bar height

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, header

I have created a webpage. However, my navigation bar's height increases or decreases when I change the size of my logo image. At the moment, the image size is small, but it has increased my navigation bar's height. It seems to have no issues when I put in a logo and class like this,
  Didacum
I have tried several times to no avail. This problem occurs when I insert an image as a logo. What can I do to fix this?

HTML

```
<header class="header">

   <a href="home.html" class="logo"> <i><img src="images/dacum.png" alt="dacum"></i></a>

   <nav class="navbar">
      <div id="close-navbar" class="fas fa-times"></div>
      <div id="close-navbar" class="fas fa-times"></div>
      <a href="home.html">Home</a>
      <a href="teacher.html">Teacher Pro Dev't</a>
      <a href="education.html">Educational Research</a>
      <a href="student.html">Student Dev't</a>
      <a href="consulting.html">School Consulting</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <!--<a href="courses.html">Courses</a>-->
      <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
   </nav>

   <div class="icons">
      <div id="account-btn" class="fas fa-user"></div>
      <div id="menu-btn" class="fas fa-bars"></div>
   </div>

</header>


CSS

     .header {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background: #fff;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
              box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 2rem 10%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
    
    .header img {
      margin-top: -10;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      padding-bottom: -20em;
    }
    
    .header .logo {
      margin-right: auto;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      color: #444;
      font-weight: bolder;
    }
    
    .header .logo i {
      color: #0eb582;
    }
    
    .header .navbar {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .header .navbar #close-navbar {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1.5rem;
      right: 2rem;
      font-size: 4rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #444;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .header .navbar #close-navbar:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
              transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    
    .header .navbar a {
      margin-right: 2rem;
      font-size: 2rem;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      color: #444;
    }
    
    .header .navbar a:hover {
      color: #0eb582;
    }
    
    .header .icons div {
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      color: #444;
      margin-left: 1.5rem;
    }
    
    .header .icons div:hover {
      color: #0eb582;
    }
    
    .header #menu-btn {
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: You can utilize the max-height CSS property to resolve this issue. For example, add a max-height: 40px; to the .header style in your CSS and then change the height/width of the .header img and you will see that the image will change but the height of the header will remain the same and won't change based on the height value you assign it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height

Comment: Note: The way you currently built the header styles, you are creating the height of the header with the padding, so when the logo image changes slightly, it will push everything up/down which is the issue you are experiencing.
P.S. You cannot use negative values for padding, you should remove that in your CSS. Only negative margin values are acceptable

Comment: @EdgarReynaga, this was helpful. I removed the negative values for padding and used the max-height. It worked perfect.